# Function successfully writes to file but contents do not show

Tags: c, function, file-io

I have two functions that uses up a `.dat` file.
The first function adds a structure of a question and its answers to the file and the other is to view the questions in the file.

The `addQues()` function is called `main` inside a loop that inquires if the user wants to add more questions. The problem is when the `addQues()` function is called the second time and onward, it successfully writes the question to the file but when the `viewQues()` function is called, the questions are not shown. The size of the file also increases after each succeeding call of `addques()`

```
/*  the structure is as follows */
typedef struct {
    char question[256];
    char choiceA[32];
    char choiceB[32];
    char choiceC[32];
    char choiceD[32];
    char ans;
    int num;    
}question;

/* function to add questions */
void addQues(){
    FILE *fileptr;
    question catcher, ques;
    int x;


    fileptr = fopen("Questions.dat", "a+");
    if(fileptr != NULL){
        catcher.num = 0;
        while(fread(&catcher, sizeof(question), 1, fileptr)!= 0){}

        printf("There are %d questions. Please type in the Question you would like to add.\n\nQuestion: ", catcher.num);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &ques.question);

        printf("Add four[4] choices to the question\n");

        printf("\nChoice a.: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &ques.choiceA);

        printf("\nChoice b.: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &ques.choiceB);

        printf("\nChoice c.: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &ques.choiceC);

        printf("\nChoice d.: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &ques.choiceD);

        printf("\nType the letter of the correct answer of this question.\nAnswer: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &ques.ans);

        ques.num = catcher.num+1;

        printf("%s", ques.question); /* made this snippet to make sure that white spaces in my input were recorded */
        getch();

        if(fwrite(&ques, sizeof(question), 1,fileptr) == 1){
            printf("File write was successful\n"); /* made this snippet to make sure if writing is successful. and it is successfull everytime */
        }else{
            printf("File write was unsuccessfull");
        }
        getch();
        fclose(fileptr);
    }else{
        printf("File either not found or does not exist.");
    }


}

/* code view the Questions in the file */

void viewQues(){
    FILE *fp;
    question ques;

    fp = fopen("Questions.dat", "r");
    if(fp != NULL){
        while(fread(&ques, sizeof(question), 1, fp) != 0){
            printf("[%d] %s\n", ques.num, ques.question);
            }

        fclose(fp);
    }else{
        printf("File is either not found or does not exist.");
    }

}
```

I am somehow confused because it somethimes works fluidly, sometimes it doesn't.

This is only my 1st semester of taking up C-programming so I still have alot to learn.
I am also quite new to this website please do forgive me if I may have violated any required format.

EDIT:  
The program requires the user to input a question, 4 choices, and it's correct answer.

in the `addQues` function before the program asks for input, it already notifies the user how many questions there are in the file.

example is  
*There are 0  question/s (this updates when a question is added). lease type in the Question you would like to add.*  
  
*Question: //user types What is the capital of Philippines?*

*Enter  Choice A: // user types 'Manila'*  
*Enter Choice B: // user types 'Cebu'*  
*Enter Choice C:// user types 'Davao'*  
*Enter Choice C:// user types 'Palawan'*

*Enter the letter of the correct answer: // User types in 'a'*

Expected output would be

*[1] What is the capital of Philippines?*

after the second call and onwards the output that it shows is still only

*[1] What is the capital of Philippines?*

I am sorry I do not know how to make the sample scenario different from the rest of the text.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a minimal example of the Questions.dat file. Show also an example of input and actuel/desired output

Comment: Save time and enable all compiler warnings.  Much faster feedback than a SO post.

Comment: A problem with this code stems from using `scanf( ...` , `getch();` and and not checking the result.  Although fixable, it a weak design choice. I recommend to replace all user input with `fgets()`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. `conio.h` is incredibly obsolete. You need a better source of learning C, your current one is teaching you bad practice.

Comment: You don't need, and shouldn't use, the `&` in `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &ques.question);` and related calls.  You should check the result from `scanf()`; you should limit the amount of data accepted to the size of the array: `if (scanf("%255[^\n]"%*c", ques.question) != 1) { …problem!… }`.  You probably need to worry about overlong answers; for symmetry, you should worry about overlong questions, too.